# Looping .wav file

Tags: ios, audio, wav

I am making an alarm app for iPhones and want to continuously loop the audio until the button is pressed again. As of now all it does is play the audio once when pressed. Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)PlayAudioButton:(id)sender {

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PlaySoundID);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSURL *SoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"wav"]];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL, &PlaySoundID);

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an AVAudioPlayer. That's what it's for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/rate) to play the sound. You must add `AVFoundation.framework` to your project for this to work. Start by declaring an `AVAudioPlayer` object. It must be declared either as a property with a `strong` attribute, e.g.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

or as an instance variable with a `__strong` attribute

```
@interface Class : SuperClass //or @implementation Class
{
    AVAudioPlayer __strong *audioPlayer;
}
```

Then, to load and play the file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithString:audioFilePath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //plays indefinitely
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}


- (IBAction)PlayAudioButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([audioPlayer isPlaying])
        [audioPlayer pause]; //or "[audioPlayer stop];", depending on what you want
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
}
```

and, when you want to stop playing the sound, call

```
[audioPlayer stop];
```